# ionic/angular, How to force client to clean his browser cache after each release?

Tags: angular, caching, ionic3

I have developed an app using ionic-native 4.7.0.
Each time I want to publish my app online I use the command `ionic build --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs`. This is great but my client still get old JS and CSS. They have to clean browser cache in order to see evolutions.

Here a picture of my "compiled" sources :
[image]

My 0.js, 1.js, ... Are lazy loaded pages and cached by my client browser. How can I force browser to reset cache after each deployement ?

Thanks !

Comment: I wonder why this problem does not bother thousands of people but only us. This issue was the biggest headache for me when using Ionic 3. Maybe I'm doing something wrong on my webserver...?

Comment: IDK... I had to use gulp and customize my tasks with some workarounds like ?v=1

Answer (score 4):

I found a working solution at https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bundled-files-and-cache-busting-lazy-loading/109114/9

Create the file `config/webpack.config.js` in your project with the following content:

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    const defaultWebpackConfig = require('../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

    module.exports = function () {
        defaultWebpackConfig.prod.output['chunkFilename'] = "[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js";
        defaultWebpackConfig.dev.output['chunkFilename'] = "[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js";
        return defaultWebpackConfig;
    };
```

Reference this config in your `package.json`:

```
    "config": {
        "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
    }
```

Then the files `0.js`, `1.js`, ... will get random names like `0.91d798902e4dca77e704.chunk.js`, no caching problem any more!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use cache versioning

At the end of file path add ?v={the version}
Like this

```
<script src="build/main.js?v=1"></script>
```

Comment: For main.js yes it works but how can I do that with my lazy loaded js handled by ionic ?

Comment: Which ones are loaded by ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @andi's suggestion. Here is my `ionic_webpack.config.js`

```
const defaultWebpackConfig = require("../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js");

module.exports = function() {
    defaultWebpackConfig.output["filename"] = "[name].[chunkhash].js";
    return defaultWebpackConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build it for production:

```
ionic cordova build browser --release --prod
```